# What is the better practice for single page application development using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, single-page-application

I am very new to jQuery and I need to do a single page application using jQuery ajax. When I searched on the internet I saw different types of JavaScript frameworks for the SPA development with different perspectives.

I mostly prefer to have structured model for the client side development as my system is going to deal with many views and objects.

I kindly request help on this with the existing optimized architectures for single page application development.

Answer (score 1):

When you create SPAs, the best practice so far is to structure your JavaScript client using an MVC approach. There is an enourmous amount of JavaScript SPA frameworks out there like

- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org)
- [Spine](http://spinejs.com/)
- [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)
- [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com)
- [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)
- ...

...just to mention some

[Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com) (together with others) created a simple TODO application which showcases the different frameworks. So the best I can suggest you is to go to [todomvc.com](http://todomvc.com) and see which one works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I work with Jquery daily, its very important to make a very clear structure of your Javascript At the end your dealing with Javascript here and not Java or any structured language.

What i did is simple, im not sure if it will help you...
You can approach this with MVC mentality:

Model - View - Controller

So this one page application can have the jquery include:

Then under it you defile our model your view your controller.

It can take you longer to understand it but believe me on the long run your winning, you can find here more info: http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/

---

The other approach you can make which is easier indeed but not cleaner, create a library that you will use for your project and call functions from it.